# Mysite web application

Tags: sharepoint-server, mysite

We have old SP 2010 with up and running mysite, and we have new SP 2013, and I am configuring mysite for the new server.
If I want to have the same URL name for mysite like what it is in SP 2010 (mysite.company.com) what is my options?

1. If I change the DNS record to point to the new server, is it ok?
2. or just simply change the mysite to my.company.com?

Comment: any plan to migrate mysite to sharepoint 2013 farm? any body using mysite in sharepoint 2010?

Comment: No. Actually I created mysite on Sp2013 from scratch. to avoid any error

Answer (score 0):

It's OK if you have migrated the Content Database from 2010 to 2013 and upgraded the database to 2013. You can chose to have users themselves upgrade their look and feel to 2013, or (using an admin account) perform the upgrade in 2013.

When you're done - point your DNS to the new WFE-server (or load balancer).

Comment: Actually, in my case i am not migrating the DB because i am configuring SP2013 from 0 level and will have both SP (2010 and 2013) working at the same time until i completely configure the new server, then I will stop the SP2010.

Comment: @ZakariaQabbani OK - then you're good to go. Just make sure you add Alternate Access Mapping to your old mysite, so users can access the old mysite and the new mysite at the same time (for moving documents and such).